# What are some functions $f \in L^\infty(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, lebesgue-integral

In my text book all it said about $L^\infty(\Omega)$ space is that it is the space of all measurable functions that are bounded almost everywhere. No example given.

I can't see how any member of this space would be useful. Perhaps $f = e^{-ax}$ would be a member of $L^\infty(\Omega)$ space? But it is more useful in a $L^2(\Omega)$ context i.e. signal analysis.

Can someone provide some motivating example of common functions $f$ such that $f \subset L^\infty(\Omega)$?

Comment: $f=1$ in $\Omega$ is a useful function for signal analysis too (a constant disturbance, for example).

Comment: Characteristic functions of measurable subsets of $\Omega$ are $L^\infty$.

Comment: in fact people love bounded functions. an other example are continuous functions with compact support. very useful in many approximation arguments